# 20k views in one weekend?

Tags: discussion, questions

[Is coffee a good excuse for a slow application start-up time?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/is-coffee-a-good-excuse-for-a-slow-application-start-up-time) question had around 1k views over the first 5 days, and all of a sudden the question had like 20k+ over the course of a weekend.

Can anyone explain what happened? I tried to check [Data](http://data.stackexchange.com/about) but there's no table for referrers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [posted on Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4824410), they're generally the culprit for these spikes (more rarely Reddit).The site's referrers analytics (mod only info we can only give "big picture" descriptions of) shows that Hacker News' referrer counts account for much of that 20k.

Comment: It's a shame that the comments made there are kept outside the SE community...